# The expression "lay fast of"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I encountered this expression when reading [John Adams by David McCullough](https://books.google.fr/books?id=GHMnz8G0GTcC&pg=PA383&lpg=PA383&dq=adams%20is%20not%20known%20to%20have%20recorded%20any%20of%20his%20thoughts&source=bl&ots=9ncLU2UQDi&sig=8D1_ZvyYqrQdgH988lUovJLrtYI&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=adams%20is%20not%20known%20to%20have%20recorded%20any%20of%20his%20thoughts&f=false),

> Adams is not known to have recorded any of his thoughts during the voyage home, but earlier he had said his great desire was " to ***lay fast of*** the town of Braintree and embrace it with both arms and all my might. There live, there to die, there to lay my bones, and there to plant one of my sons in the profession of law and the practices of agriculture, like his father."

The context of the above excerpt is in 1788, when Adams's were recalled from London as U.S. ambassador back home to Braintree, Massachusetts.

The closest fitting definition I found out comes from Dictionary.com, which gives "Nautical. to take up a specified position, direction, etc". But I am not sure. Any other takes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [phrase](https://founders.archives.gov/documents/Adams/04-08-02-0064) is actually "to lay fast hold of..." The important word here is *hold.*

To [*lay hold of*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/lay-hold-of)  means to grasp or hold and the adjective *fast*, in this context, most likely means tight or firm.  So, the phrase as a whole means that he's going to hold on tightly to his roots in the town.